# How to get all books from another table when using many to many relationship Laravel / Eloquent / Query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Let me explain the scenario.

i have tables:

`competitions`

`id         title          body`

then

`books`

`id        name     user_id`

then i have a pivot table to store `participants`

so

`participants`

`id             competition_id           user_id`

Now i have set some relationships for these models.

`Competition` model

```
 public function participants()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
```

`User` model

```
 public function participatedCompetitions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Competition');
    }
```

Now i am fetching one single competition and in that same query i need to fetch a list of books of the participants of that competition. 
So how can i achieve this.
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you get all the books:

```
$userIds = $competition->participant()->get()->pluck('id');
// $userIds is your collection of User Ids that is participant in that compititions.
$books = Book::whereIn('user_id',$userIds)->get();
```

Comment: This approach leads to 2 queries instead of one. FYI.